# Styling and adding pop ups to leaflet-geojson-vt

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

TDLR: Is it possible to style and make vector tile layer interactive?

I implemented a geojson file with the leaflet-geojson-vt plugin. Is there any chance I can style the points with a function and add a pop up to it? This is the code:

```
var data= <script src="./dataset.js"></script>  
var options = {
            maxZoom: 20,
            tolerance: 3,
            debug: 0};
var canvasLayer = L.geoJson.vt(data, options,).addTo(map);
```

This works fine, but I like to have functions for Styling the Points by categories and the popup function implemented. Let's call them {onEachFeature: forEachFeaturePopup,pointToLayer:Categories}. How can I implement these in the vt layer? Is this even possible?

Comment: look into `L.vectorGrid.protobuf`

Comment: Looks promising, but I ain't able to get my points styled. I will open a new question on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also use [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) and use mapbox-gl styling for your vector layers.